# android slideshow view with wipe gesture and pinch zoom

Tags: java, android, eclipse, slideshow

How to implement android slide show effect for displaying set of images (one at time) and sliding between them using gestures (wipe left/right)?
How to implement zooming of image using pinch gesture?
Are there any examples?

Thanks